# Local agent won't connect to VSO

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Trying to set up a local build agent behind the company proxy, so after extracting the agent zip provided by VSO I set it up by running:

```
.\config.cmd --proxyurl http://(corporate stuff):8083/proxy.pac
```

(There's no user or password)

I entered the server URL: `https://myproject.visualstudio.com`, used the PAT token I generated on VSO, used Default agent pool and put in an agent name.  All of that seemed to work (shows up in VSO now), but when I `.\run.cmd`, I get

`2018-07-19 19:54:12Z: Agent connect error: Not Implemented. Retrying until reconnected.`

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: How about using `./config.cmd --proxyurl http://(corporate stuff):8083 --proxyusername "" --proxypassword ""`?

Comment: Hi! Just tried that, same result: `2018-07-20 12:26:22Z: Agent connect error: Not Implemented. Retrying until reconnected.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the content of the .pac file, see what is proxy address listed in it, remove the agent configuration and configure it again picking a working proxy address.

Comment: Thanks! PAC file had a specific IP and using that worked.

Comment: consider that the proxy administrator may change this in the future: better get in touch with them